# Proving that f is a constant on a nonempty open disc

Tags: complex-analysis

If you start with $f: \Bbb C \to  \Bbb C$, and we let it be entire. And we let $\Bbb D$ be a nonempty open disc on $\Bbb C$, such that $f(z)$ does not attain any values in the disc. Is it possible to show that $f$ is a constant?

Comment: what does "does not attain any values" means?

Comment: non-constant entire functions hit all values in $\Bbb C$

Comment: @MatthewLevy Entire functions can miss one value like $e^z.$

Comment: but an open disk has uncountable points

Comment: Look for Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: Let $z_0$ be at the center of the disk.  Then consider the function $g(z)=\frac1{f(z)-z_0}$.  You should be able to show that this function is bounded and entire. Apply Liouville's Theorem.  Then, what does this say about $f$?

Comment: As long it's possible to show that f is bounded and analytic, I assume that the proof is so assume that |f(z)| is less or equal to B for all z in C. and we estimate to a disk centered at any z0, of any radius N, we will get
|f'(z0)| less or equal to B/N, where B is a Bound for f and letting tend R to infinity, we will get f'(z0)=0. And since this is true for all z0, f(z) is constant. I guess this it how it should be? But this is as long f is bounded and analytic?

Comment: It might be slightly clearer to call the center of the disk $w_0$. It's too easy to think of $z_0$, like $z$, as being in the domain.